# least frequent common number from a int array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, array-algorithms

I have to find least common number from an int array , I have written code but it is not working properly ,

Here is my logic, 
1. sort the array 
2. get min common counter updated
3. get if all are unique

and the code below,

```
static int min_loc ; //minimum value location 
static int min_cnt ;
int all_uniqFlag = true;

void leastCommon(int data[],int n)
{
   int rcount = 0; //Repeated number counter
   int mcount = n; // minimum repetetion counter;

   // The array is already sorted we need to only find the least common value. 
   for(int i = 0 ; i < n-1 ; i++)
   {  
      //Case A : 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 5 : result should be 4 
      //Case B : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 (All unique number and common values so all values should be printed
      //                        and ) 
      //Case C : 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 (all numbers have same frequency so need to display all )
      cout << "data[i] : " << data[i] << " data[i+1] : " << data[i+1] <<  "i = " << i << endl;
      if(data[i] != data[i+1])
      {
         //mcount = 0;
         //min_loc = i; 
         //return;
      }
      if(data[i] == data[i+1])
      {
        all_uniqFlag = false;
        rcount++;
      }
      else if(rcount < mcount)
      {
         mcount = rcount;
         min_loc = i ;//data[i];
      }
   } 
   min_cnt = mcount;   
}
```

As mentioned in the comment only Case B works and Case A and C is not working could you help me fix the issue ?

Comment: 'cout' is C++; perhaps you should exchange the 'c' flag for 'c++'?

Comment: Code can't work in `else if(data[i] ! = `, fix it first.

Comment: Edited i have complied the code without that else if(data..) part ..

Comment: @cslrnr: scan through the list and count the # of occurrences of each element.find the minimum count.print all the elements which match the minimum count. Code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- scan through the list
- compare each element in the list with the last element in the `out` array
- If the element matches, then increment its count by 1
- If the element doesn't match then add the new element into `out`
  array and increment `index` by 1

Once the scan is done, the `out` array will have all the distinct elements`out[][0]` and their frequencies `out[][1]`

- Scan through the frequency list (`out[][1]`) to find the lowest frequency
- Finally do another scan through the element list `out[][0]` and print elements whose frequency matches with the lowest frequency

.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 8
int main()
{
    //int data[N]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int data[N]={1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4};
    //int data[N]={1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5};
    int out[N][2];
    int i=0,index=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        out[i][0]=0; 
        out[i][1]=0; 
    }
    out[0][0] = data[0];
    out[0][1]=1;
    for(i=1;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(data[i] != out[index][0])
        {
            index++;
            out[index][0] = data[i];
            out[index][1] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            out[index][1]++;
        }
    }

    int min=65536;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(out[i][1] == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        if(out[i][1] < min)
        {
            min = out[i][1];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(out[i][1] == min)
        {
            printf("%d\t",out[i][0]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `map` for this:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::map<int, int> Counter;

void leastCommon(int data[],int n) {
    Counter counter;
    int min = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        counter[data[i]]++;
    for (Counter::iterator it = counter.begin(); it != counter.end(); it++) {
        if (min > it->second) min = it->second;
    }   
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (counter[data[i]] == min) {
            std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
            counter[data[i]]++;
        }   
    }   
}

int main() {
    int data[] = {1, 1,3,4,4,2,4,3,2};
    leastCommon(data, 9); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I only need to use linear arrays  and maps are not allowed since it is a practice code..

Comment: counter is an int -> int map, it maps a value to the frequency so the index is the value. `counter[ data[i] ]` refers to the frequency of the value in `data[i]`. `counter[data[i]]++` is incrementing the frequency by 1, in your example, `counter[4]++` will be done 3 times and in the end of the loop `counter[4]` will be 3.

Comment: is that Counter datatype is defined  in <maps> ? or it is from <iostream> std library ?

Comment: It is defined above: `typedef std::map<int, int> Counter;`

Answer (score 1):

Approach is-

- select 1st element from the sorted array, and while consecutive elements to it are same, store them in output[] until the loop breaks
- store the frequency of element in leastFrequency
- select next element, check with its consecutive ones and store them in same output[] until the loop breaks
- check frequency of this with the leastFrequency

  - if same, do nothing (let these be added in the output[])
  - if less, clear output[] and store the element same no. of times
  - if more, change the effective output[] length to previous length before iterating for this element
- similarly iterate for all distinct elements and finally get the result from output[] from 0 to effective length

  ```
  void leastCommon(int data[], int len) {

  if ( len > 0) {
      int output[] = new int[len];
      int outlen = 0; // stores the size of useful-output array
      int leastFrequency = len; // stores the lowest frequency of elements

      int i=0;
      int now = data[i];
      while (i < len) {
          int num = now;
          int count = 0;
          do {
              output[outlen] = now;
              outlen++;
              count++;

              if((++i == len)){
                  break;
              }
              now = data[i];
          } while (num == now);   // while now and next are same it adds them to output[] 

          if (i - count == 0) { // avoids copy of same values to output[] for 1st iteration
              leastFrequency = count;
          } else if (count < leastFrequency) {  // if count for the element is less than the current minimum then re-creates the output[]
              leastFrequency = count;
              output = new int[len];
              outlen = 0;
              for (; outlen < leastFrequency; outlen++) {    
                  output[outlen] = num;   // populates the output[] with lower frequent element, to its count 
              }
          } else if (count > leastFrequency) {
              outlen -= count;    // marks outlen to its same frequent numbers, i.e., discarding higher frequency values from output[]
          }
      }
      //for(int j = 0; j < outlen; j++) {
      // print output[] to console
      //}
    }
  }
  ```

Plz suggest for improvements.

Comment: Coded in Java, later altered it to make compatible for C/C++. If any mistake, then plz correct me.